# How do I remove a username from the username drop down list on Chrome on Mac OS X?

Tags: google-chrome

Googling suggests that I highlight the name with my mouse and hit delete - this doesn't work (the name stays in the dropdown list, I instead end up deleting a letter from the name textfield)

A Mac specific suggestion is to hold down the "fn" button when I click delete. Trying that seems to have no effect - nothing changes, that I can see.

How do I remove a specific username from the username drop down on Google Chrome on Mac?

---

To all the answers suggesting <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Delete ⌫</kbd> It is an editor shortcut for "quick delete entire line". So it only *looks* like it works.

It does ***not*** add/modify/delete names from the list of login names that are suggested for autofill.

Please test your answer before posting - make ***sure*** that the auto-fill list is actually different after you've deleted a name.

Comment: If you mean account information saved in a keychain, you can delete it from Keychain Access.

Comment: @LauriRanta No, not that - just the list of login names that show up for the name field on forms. I'd like to edit the list, not blow away all of them.

Comment: @blueberryfields I think you meant autofill in data. You can click Ctrl+, which goes to Preferences there you can click on clear browsing data. There you can select the check box "Clear saved Autofill form data".

Comment: @garikapati As I've said in the question and in my comment above, I'm explicitly looking to edit the list of login names, not to blow away all of them.

Comment: My rep isn't enough to leave an answer: To clear usernames or emails from login forms in chrome - go to chrome preferences, look for "Manage passwords".  You can filter by domain.  Delete the accounts from there.

Answer (score 21):

Was actually having the same trouble and decided to try a combination of <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>

Comment: And did it work?

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: Type something on the address bar.  The hint appears.  Click down arrow until the item you want to delete is highlighted.  Then, click fn+shift+delete.

Answer (score 0):

Running Chrome v28 on OS X 10.8.4, by selecting an entry in a dropdown of saved usernames, I was able to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete ⌫</kbd> and remove the incorrect name.

Comment: are you sure that it's removed from the list? what happens if you start typing names again? When I try this, the name that's in the text box is deleted, but doesn't appear to be permanently removed from the auto-fill list.

Answer (score 0):

highlight the name with the mouse and hit<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. It worked for me.

Comment: It would help if you can elaborate on your answer and provide detailed steps.

Answer (score -1):

The Ctrl+Shift+Delete worked for me. When the drop down options appear, use arrow keys to highlight the option you want to delete, then Ctrl+Shift+Delete removes that option.

Fn + Shift + Delete worked for me.  Sightly different key combination from most of this thread.